# C# invoking an C API which takes an char ** pointer as parameter

Tags: c#, c, dll

I'm developing an desktop application using C#, which has to call these APIs from an C++ dll:

```
int send_message(void * handle, char * message, size_t len);
int recv_message(void * handle, char ** message, size_t * len, int timeout);
```

`send_message` sends some text to the server, `recv_message` receives messages from the server.
`recv_message` allocates a buffer to hold the data, then pass the pointer back to its caller.

After consulting some web links, I've already managed to call the `send_message` API from my app like this:

```
// import API from DLL
[DllImport("test.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "send_message")]
extern static int send_message(IntPtr handle, string message, int len);

// invoke the API
public int SendMessage(string message)
{
    return send_message(this.client, message, message.Length);
}
```

But I failed to invoke the 2nd API, I got stuck on the `char **` and `size_t *` parameters.

Any idea?

Comment: `ref IntPtr`, but you had better have another function in the DLL to free the buffer, because C# garbage collection will not handle it for you.

Comment: @BenVoigt thanks a lot for mentioning that. It seems a pre-allocated buffer from C# to DLL would be a better choice, is it? anyway, I'll give `ref IntPtr` a try.

Comment: You have posted the code that works, while omitting the code that does not and about which you are asking.  It would make more sense perhaps to post the problematic code. Post your attempt and the exact errors or erroneous behaviour that occur.

Comment: @Clifford being a newbie to C# world, actually I've no idea where to start. I studied `ref` and `out` keywords, but still don't know the inner details of how they interoperate with DLL.now I'm reading some docs on the Marshal interfaces. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to the original question. It's a **workaround**.
I still want to know the answer to the original question. It itches.

---

Inspired by the comment, I think it's more reasonable to allocate the buffer at C# side, and pass it to the DLL.

Here's the new API added to DLL.

```
int recv_message2(void * handle, char * message, size_t len, int timeout);
```

Here's the import statement in C#.

```
[DllImport("test.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "recv_message2")]
extern static int recv_message2(IntPtr handle, IntPtr buffer, int len, int timeout);
```

To invoke it in C#:

```
IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(1024);
int ret = recv_message2(this.client, buffer, 1024, timeout);
if (ret > 0)
{
    byte[] myByteArray = new byte[ret];
    Marshal.Copy(buffer, myByteArray, 0, ret);
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(myByteArray);
}
```

Hope it helps.